# my flutter project is does not connect to firebase

Tags: flutter

my all files are all set 
pubspec.yaml,
build.gradle,
google play file ,
firebase rules are true 
depencies and plugins too
are all set ,

but when was running app 
i am getting this error

```
2019-12-18 01:55:07.471 1784-7483/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 33694500 , only wrote 33694475
2019-12-18 01:55:07.736 19562-19694/com.example.resat I/flutter: Data : [null, {description: Programming Guide for J2EE, title: Mastering EJB}, {description: Complete Programming Guide to learn Flutter, title: Flutter in Action}]
```

Here is my code,

```
    final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Firebase Connect'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[

              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Createeee Record'),
                onPressed: () {
                  createRecord();
                },
              ),

              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('View Record'),
                onPressed: () {
                  getData();
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Udate Record'),
                onPressed: () {
                  updateData();
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Delete Record'),
                onPressed: () {
                  deleteData();
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
      ), //center
    );
     }

      void createRecord(){
      databaseReference.child("1").set({
      'title': 'Mastering EJB',
      'description': 'Programming Guide for J2EE'
      });
      databaseReference.child("2").set({
      'title': 'Flutter in Action',
      'description': 'Complete Programming Guide to learn Flutter'
    });
     }
    void getData(){
     databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    });
    }

    void updateData(){
     databaseReference.child('1').update({
       'description': 'J2EE complete Reference'
     });
    }

     void deleteData(){
     databaseReference.child('1').remove();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the exact error you are getting? and did you try removing the getData() call from the build method?